# Django update all Users field Decimal

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

```
from decimal import Decimal
from apps.main.models import User
from django.db.models import F

User.objects.all().update(freeze_balance=F('freeze_balance')  + Decimal(F('balance') / 8300))
```

> ERROR -> TypeError: conversion from CombinedExpression to Decimal is
>   not supported

How do I write an ORM request for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining `Decimal` and `F` expression is not supported in django. Try below code

```
User.objects.all().update(freeze_balance=F('freeze_balance')  + F('balance') / 8300)
```